# How can I remove all tags except an allowed list from html parsed by php

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument, php-parser

I am parsing html in php and as I have no control over the original content I want to strip it of styling and unnecessary tags while still keep the content and a short list of tags, namely:

p, img, iframe (and maybe a couple of others)

I know I can remove a given tag **(see code I am using for this below**), but as I don't necessarily know what tags their could possibly be, and I don't want to create a huge list of possibles, I would like to be able to strip everything except my allowed list.

```
function DOMRemove(DOMNode $from) {
    $sibling = $from->firstChild;

    do {
        $next = $sibling->nextSibling;
        $from->parentNode->insertBefore($sibling, $from);
    } while ($sibling = $next);

    $from->parentNode->removeChild($from);
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
```

Comment: Oddly enough there is a function called strip_tags that's already built into PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Oh dear :(, a classic case of tunnel vision. I should have considered this approach before. THANKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As spoken by [cpattersonv1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145800/cpattersonv1) above, you can simply use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for the job.

```
<?php

// strip all other tags except mentioned (p, img, iframe)
$html_result = strip_tags($html, '<p><img><iframe>');

?>
```